# React render a blank page on production mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs

I launch my nodejs server and it render a blank page but I can see in the chrome inspector it's rendering my `index.html` from my react build but inside the tag `<div id='root'></div>` there is nothing.

In the inspector console I have this problem

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.a3362a52.chunk.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index.bundle.js:1
```

So I guess I can't render my components because of this error/

With my search I found two possibilities to explore.

First I tried to solve this syntax error problem, I found out it could be a problem with babel so I try to write in my `index.html`
    
It remove the syntax error about `index.bundle.js` but the other one on the chunk is still here since it's generated by my react build.

Then I tried to see if there is a problem with the router, so in my `index.js` I typed 
    ReactDOM.render(test, document.getElementById('root'));
but this div didn't render so I guess it's not a router problem.

My `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>my app</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
  <script src="index.bundle.js" type = "text/jsx">
  </script>
</html>
```

my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename='/'>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

my `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
      ["react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "./public/messages/"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              mimetype: 'image/png'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx'
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './build'
  }
}
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'));
module.exports = config;
```

So I think the problem come from babel but I don't know how to solve it, do you have any idea or other way I should explore for solving my problem ?

thank you

**EDIT**

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "None",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "mongoDir": "/usr/local"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "b64-to-blob": "1.2.19",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "bootstrap-select": "1.13.2",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "country-select-js": "2.0.1",
    "domino": "2.1.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "express-session": "1.15.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "3.7.8",
    "i18next": "^12.1.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "js-string-compression": "1.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "1.14.3",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.0.6",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.1.3",
    "react-cookie": "^3.0.8",
    "react-country-region-selector": "^1.4.3",
    "react-dev-utils": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-flags-select": "^1.1.9",
    "react-google-login": "^4.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.12",
    "react-i18next": "^8.3.8",
    "react-intl": "^2.7.2",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-sidebar": "^3.0.2",
    "react-youtube": "^7.8.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.4.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3",
    "youtube-player": "5.5.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/compression": "0.0.36",
    "@types/cors": "2.8.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.10",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.116",
    "@types/node": "8.10.20",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "codelyzer": "4.4.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "protractor": "5.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.10.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:langs && node scripts/build.js && npm run compile ",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./build/index.bundle.js",
    "compile": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:langs": "NODE_ENV='production' babel-node scripts/mergeMessages.js"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~8.11.3",
    "npm": "~5.6.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: webpack related issue, see [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2882) maybe you will find something useful.

Comment: But on this issue it's seems to be a router problem but when I replace the inside of my `ReactDOM.render` by `<div>something</div>` I still have a blank page but i'm not using any route.

Comment: are you trying to deploy the app on the domain root or in sub directory ?

Comment: I do `node ./server/server.js` from the root

Comment: as you are transpiling the app change the `script tag` type to `text/javascript` or remove it all together. Does it work in the development env ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi When I'm in development mode I start react server and node js server at the same time and I go on the `localhost:3000`. Here I just start nodejs server and go on `localhost:5000`

Comment: did you try changing the type in script tag ? also can you add the package.json as well with webpack and babel versions you are using ?

Comment: I try to change the type in script but still not working. I have edited my first message with my package.json, i'm using `webpack v 4.19.1` and `babel v 7.1.6`